# How to find the solution of $\sqrt{x^2+12x+35} \geq x-10$?

Tags: inequality, radical-equations

I want to ask about radical inequality problem.

Here's the question:

Find the solution sets for $\sqrt{x^2+12x+35}\geq x-10$

My attempts to tackle this problem is like this:

Firstly I try to squaring this inequality such that:

$x^2+12x+35\geq (x-10)^2$

$x^2+12x+35\geq x^2-20x+100$

$x=\frac{65}{32}$

And then I apply the condition for the form under the radical, such that:

$x^2+12x+35\geq 0$ and also for the right hand, such that: $x-10\geq 0$

I solve for both of them and got $x\leq -7$ and $x\geq -5$ for the first one and $x>=10$ for the right hand.

Then, I combine all of the solutions to get whole solutions $x>=10$

From my number line, I can conclude that the solution should be $x\geq 10$

But, when I'm trying to check it in wolfram, I got the solution should be $x\leq 7$ or $x\geq -5$

Please somebody explain to me about this difference, so I can get the right answer from this problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why the condition $x-10\ge0$? If $x-10<0$ and the radical is well defined, surely the inequality holds, right?

Comment: First you have to sate the constraint on your inequality . This inequality make senses only when term under square root is nonnegative . Add9ng to this it becomes obvious when the left hand side is non-positif.

Comment: @Did, I think the radical inequallty must have a condition for right hand side $a>= 0$ , such that this inequality can be holds? Maybe, you can explain to me about your statement? thanks

Comment: You have 1200 rep and haven't learned $\geq$ yet? Wow... just wow.

Comment: akusaja What? Sorry but did you even *read* my comment? I mean, carefully.

Comment: @Did, based on your comment, I think the right hand side condition should be less than or equal zero, right? or we need another condition to find the solution? sorry for my misunderstanding. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to sate the constraint on your inequality . This inequality make senses only when term under square root is nonnegative . 
i.e $$x^2+12x+35\ge 0\Longleftrightarrow (x+5)(x+7)\ge 0\Longleftrightarrow x\in(-\infty, -7]\cup [-5, \infty)$$

Adding to this it becomes obvious when the left hand side is non-positif. ie if

$$ x-10\le 0 \Longleftrightarrow x\in (-\infty ,10]$$

So, if $x\in (-\infty ,10]\cap((-\infty, -7]\cup [-5, \infty)) =(-\infty, -7]\cup [-5,10]$ we have 
 $\sqrt{x^2+12x+35} >= x-10$

Now if $x\in (-\infty, -7]\cup [-5, \infty) $ and $x\in  [10, \infty)$ which means $x\in [10, \infty) $ and $x-10\ge0$ you can proceed as you did i.e

For $x\in [10, \infty)$ we have,

$$\sqrt{x^2+12x+35} >= x-10 \Longleftrightarrow x^2+12x+35\ge x^2-20x+100\Longleftrightarrow 32x \ge 65$$
Then, $x\ge 65/32 =2.03125$ and  $x\in [10, \infty)$ this implies that $x\in [10, \infty)$

> finally, $\sqrt{x^2+12x+35} >= x-10 \Longleftrightarrow x\in [10, \infty)\cup (-\infty, -7]\cup [-5,10] =(-\infty, -7]\cup [-5,\infty)$

Comment: These numbers should be $-5$ and $-7$ instead of $5$ and $7$.

Comment: you  are right I fixed it now

Answer (score 2):

We can write your equations as 
$$\sqrt{(x+6)^2-1}\ge x-10$$

For us to be able to write $$\sqrt{(x+6)^2-1}$$

It must be that $$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{x\in \Big(-\infty ,-7\Big]\cup \Big[-5,\infty \Big)}$$
$$$$$$$$
For $$ -5\le x\le 10$$
$$\sqrt{(x+6)^2-1}\ge 0\ge x-10$$
Which is true.

Hence,
$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{x\in \Big[-5,10\Big]}$$
$$$$$$$$
For $x\gt 10$
$$\sqrt{(x+6)^2-1}\ge x-10$$
$$(x+6)^2-1\ge (x-10)^2$$
$$(x+6)^2-(x-10)^2 \ge 1$$
$$((x+6)+(x-10))((x+6)-(x-10))\ge 1$$
$$(2x-4)16\ge 1$$
$$32x-64\ge 1$$
$$32x\ge 65$$
$$ x\ge \frac{65}{32}$$
But
$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{x\in \Big[10,\infty \Big)}$$

> Considering all conditions,
>   $$x\in \Big(-\infty,-7\Big]\cup \Big[-5,\infty\Big)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

- *First*, you have to determine the domain of validity of the inequation, i.e. for which values  of $x$ the radicand is non-negative. As 
  $$x^2+12x+35=(x+5)(x+7),$$
  this domain is $\;(-\infty,-7]\cup[-5,+\infty)$.
- Second, you must remember that, on the domain of validity,
  $$\sqrt A\ge B\iff A\ge B^2\quad\textbf{or}\quad B\le 0.$$

Comment: Upvoting the only reasonably sane answer in this circus.

Comment: @bernard, so the condition for the right hand side is should be less than zero? not larger than zero? thanks

Comment: It is *one* possibility, provided the l.h.s. is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^2+12x+35=y^2$, where $y\geq0$.

Thus, $x=-6-\sqrt{y^2+1}$ or $x=-6+\sqrt{y^2+1}$ and we need to solve
$$y+16\geq\sqrt{y^2+1}$$ and we need to solve

$$y+16\geq-\sqrt{y^2+1}.$$
But both inequalities are obviously true for all $y\geq0$,

which says that the starting inequality is equivalent to
$$x^2+12x+35\geq0,$$ which gives the answer:
$$(-\infty,-7]\cup[-5,+\infty).$$
Done!